# ASP.NET Calling a Method in (ASPX) From a UserControl (ASCX)?

Tags: asp.net, call, master-pages

got an `Default.aspx`

its Codebehind has a Method: `public void DoSomething(){}`

The `Default.aspx` has got a `UserControl.ascx`

In the Codebehind of my `UserControl.ascx` I would like to call my `DoSomething()` from `Default.aspx`, but this doesn't works:

```
Default defaultPage = new Default();
defaultPage.DoSomething();
```

How can I achieve this? 
(`Default.aspx` is also the StartupPage of the Masterpage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Default defaultPage = new Default();` would create a new instance of your page, which isn't what you want.

From your usercontrol, you could do something like this:

```
((Default)Page).DoSomething();
```

Or to be safe and ensure that the Page is of type Default since a user control could exist on many different pages (which is why this may not be the best idea).

```
Default p = Page as Default;
if( p != null )
    p.DoSomething();
```

Comment: thx and could u tell me how I would call a Method from an MASTERPAGE.Site in a by example Default.aspx?

Comment: Similar syntax ((MasterType)this.Master).Method()