# How to Call a Parent Method from UserControl in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a `ASP.NET Page` that contains a *Shopping Cart* `UserControl`. Now, when user `Click` on `CheckoutButton` which is in `UserControl` i want to redirect him to a page where customer information will be entered when CustomerID session is `null`.
[image]

**In UserControl:**

```
protected void lnkCheckOut_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["SalesCustomerID"] != null)
        {

            //CompleteOrder();

        }
        else
        {
            //Call here method of Parent Page 
        }
    }
```

**In Product.aspx.cs**

In `Product.aspx` page the `UserControl` exists. this page also contains the `MasterPage`.

```
 public void CallCustomerForm()
    {
      //show/redirect to customer entry form
    }
```

So, how to call a method which is in `ParentControl` from `UserControl` button click in `asp.net using c#?`

Comment: Any reason to not create an Event on the user control that the page can subscribe to, and keep the page-specific redirect code in the page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192739/how-do-i-raise-an-event-in-a-usercontrol-and-catch-it-in-mainpage

Answer (score 2):

I think you ought to stop and think about your design. Your controls should not ever need to know anything about the page that contains them - the fact that you need to go find a control on the page from within another control tells me that you ought to rethink the problem.

The best thing I can tell you (with what little I know of your architecture) is that you ought to pass in a reference to the control you hope to find into your user control. This way your control does not have to know about things outside itself.

**Similar Questions have already been answered before.**

Here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28503/Transfering-control-to-Page-ASPX-from-Control-ASCX

Here: [How to call a method from user control to aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027066/how-to-call-a-method-from-user-control-to-aspx-page)

And Lastly, Here: [ASP.NET Calling a Method in (ASPX) From a UserControl (ASCX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810548/asp-net-calling-a-method-in-aspx-from-a-usercontrol-ascx)